# Finding Degree of Freedom from 2 Logit Models

Tags: self-study, logit

Hi I have a question on finding DF in logit models. Say I have a table (all fictional numbers)

[image: 8 cities smoking vs heart disease]

and say I am testing goodness of fit (deviance) between the fitted model and saturated model.

1) main effect model : $$Logit[\pi (x,y))] = \alpha + \beta_{x}^{smoking} + \beta_{y}^{city}$$

2) Saturated model: $$ Logit[\pi (x,y))] = \alpha + \beta_{x}^{smoking} + \beta_{y}^{city} + \beta_{xy}^{smoking,city}$$

How do I calculate the DF from these 2 models? (the answer is 7 from stats software, but I don't understand how to get the answer manually). DF=degree of freedom = difference in number of parameters from the 2 models.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess that with DF you mean the number of degrees of freedom of the test comparing either model with a null model containing only the constant.

In the first model you add 7 indicator variables for city (the 8th is the reference category and is thus left out) and 1 for smoking, so in total 8 degrees of freedom

In the second model you have 7 main effects of city and 1 main effect of smoking and 7 interaction effects, so in total 15 degrees of freedom.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. However, the answer is 7 ( 2*8 - 9). I can't understand why its 2*8 (for saturated model) and 9 (for fitted model).

Comment: The answer I gave includes how I computed them, so what about that computation did you not understand? How did you get your answers?

Comment: Assuming the intercept $\alpha$ is estimated too, there's 9 & 16 degrees of freedom in each model - same difference of course.

Comment: sure, that is what I meant with the first sentence in my answer: the constant is estimated in both models, so drops out.

Comment: hi, thanks. so here's my understanding. first model: 1(intercept) + 1(smoking-2levels (yes/no) so 2-1=1 ) + 7 (8cities-1) = 9 ? And similarly, for 2nd model: 1(intercept) + 1(smoking-2levels (yes/no) so 2-1=1 ) + 7 (8cities-1) + [ (1*7) (because of interaction between smoking*city ] = 16 ? is it correct? thanks

Comment: I started my answer with the sentence: "I guess that with DF you mean the number of degrees of freedom of the test comparing either model with a null model containing only the constant." So, the constant drops out.

Comment: @Maarten You did; it does: sorry I didn't read carefully enough.